# cant install lubuntu on openelec machine

Tags: lubuntu, xbmc, usb-installation

I have a netbook with openelec installed (replacing win7).
Im trying to remove the openelec and install lubuntu but when I try to bbot from usb drive nothing happens.
can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Is the USB drive accessed when you turn your computer on? If it is check if the boot order in your netbook's BIOS is correct.

When you turn it on you have to press a key such as ESC or F2 - depending on the computer's model - to access your BIOS Setup. Make a quick Google search to find out which key is correct for your model.

Once you're in the BIOS setup you wanna look for 'Boot' and check if the USB is recognized and is being booted before your hard drive. The drives listed on top are booted first so you might have to change the order of the list to put your USB on a higher level (possibly using F5 or F6). Check 
[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kg12.png)
for a more detailed view. Once you've done that press F10 to save your changes and try to boot again.

Again all of this depends on your computer's model and your BIOS screen might be different from the one on the image. Be careful when changing these settings.

Also HowToGeek has a nice guide on how to boot a computer from a Disk or USB drive. You might wanna check it out:
https://www.howtogeek.com/129815/beginner-geek-how-to-change-the-boot-order-in-your-computers-bios/

Comment: thanks. I tried and and it didnt work.  apparently the problem was with the image file itself and the bios went throug hthe usb but found nothing. I tried using unetbootin and it worked. thanks!